# Import CSV and encodings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use Rails 3.2 and the CSV library to import CSV files.
I use it like this:

```
CSV.foreach(open(csv_url), :headers => true) do |p|
```

When I run it on my local computer it works fine, but for some reason it fails for some records on Heroku with the error:

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

It fails in a method I've defined that simply appends two strings:

```
def name_and_brand
  "#{name} #{brand.name}"
end
```

It only fails on some records though, not all.

I've read lots of information about this but I still haven't figured out how to solve it.

If I simply output the encoding of the text I'm parsing it says on my local computer that it is `UTF-8`, but on Heroku it says `ASCII-8BIT`.

If I run `"a".encoding` in the console it outputs `UTF-8` and Heroku outputs `UTF-8` too.

**What I've tried so far**

```
# in application.rb
config.encoding = "utf-8"

# in environment.rb
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

# in other files
# encoding: UTF-8
```

One difference I've found is that Heroku use Ruby 1.9.2 and I use 1.9.3 on my local machine. Could that be it?

Any ideas what I can try more?

**EDIT**

I found out that you can explicitly choose ruby version on heroku by adding `ruby "1.9.3"` in the gemfile. Seems to have fixed my issue.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p194 but I'm still having the same problem! Does anyone know how to force the encoding of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to explicitly change ruby version to 1.9.3 by adding `ruby "1.9.3"` in my Gemfile